# How to use “Look Up in Dictionary” in NSPopover Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview, nspopover

I'm building my macOS app that contains NSPopover with NSTextView inside. If "Look up & data detectors" is active at system preferences, NSTextView will support this functionality without any additional settings. But in case, when you place NSTextView inside of NSPopover, this function won't work anymore. Is there any way to fix this problem without NSTextView.showDefenition(for: at:)?

How it usually works

[image]

Same thing, but won't work with NSTextView that placed inside of NSPopover

[image]

I've started new test project just to check behaviour, so code is simple as it is.

Main Controller:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var popoverButton: NSButton!
    @IBAction func pressButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
        let popover = NSPopover()
        popover.contentViewController = PopoverController()
        popover.contentSize = CGSize(width: 470, height: 300)
        popover.show(relativeTo: popoverButton.bounds, of: popoverButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Popover Controller:

```
import Cocoa

class PopoverController: NSViewController {
    
    var textView = NSTextView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        view.addSubview(textView)
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.frame = view.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: Try seeing if Apple Script has a dictionary for it.

Comment: How do you show the popover?

Comment: Does "Look up" work if the text view in the window, not the popover, is created in code?

Comment: Yes, in case of NSWindow it works perfectly fine.